# Restrict access to Cross-region ec2 instances amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I need to design a cross-region cross-VPC architecture and i am not sure how i can restrict access to my resources
The requirement is that i need to run my web app in one region and my database in an another region.
Both the servers are inside private subnets. The web app has an auto scaling group and load balancer attached. The database server in the other region should only be accessible from this web app. I cannot use ip based restrictions as the IP of load balancer changes with time. What other option do i have?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is correct in his answer, going cross-region between app and database is definitely possible,  but it is not going to be ideal.  Do you have a specific reason for wanting to do things this way?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot We have an application that has customers from around the world and due to data-privacy laws we must save customer's private data in the same region as the customer. We are trying our best to keep as much data in the centralized database which is obviously in the same region as web server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of your Load Balancer is irrelevant because the Load Balancer is only used for incoming connections to your web server.

First, I should point out that **having your database remote from your application is a poor architectural decision**, which will slow down your application. *Please reconsider it if possible!*

You have not provided much information, so I will make the following assumptions:

- VPC in Region A contains:

  - A Load Balancer in a public subnet
  - Web servers in a private subnet
- VPC in Region B contains:

  - A database in a private subnet

In this situation, you wish to communicate between two private subnets in different VPCs that reside in different regions. For this, you could consider creating a **private VPN connection** via Amazon EC2 instances located in the public subnets of each VPC. This would use a **software VPN** such as [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) or [OpenSwan](https://www.openswan.org/).

You should also consider how to achieve a **High Availability option** for this solution. A well-architected VPC would have your web servers deployed across multiple Availability Zones in Region A, with your database preferably in a multi-AZ configuration in Region B (assuming that you are using Amazon RDS). You should similarly design your VPN solution to be highly-available in case of failure.

An alternative is to put a **NAT Server** in the public subnet of the VPC in Region A and configure the private Route Table to send traffic through the NAT Server. This means that traffic going from the web servers to the Internet would all come from the public IP address associate with the NAT Server (*not* the Load Balancer).

However, the database is in a private subnet, so the traffic cannot be directly routed to the database so this is only half a solution. It would then either require the database to be in a public subnet (with a Security Group that only accepts connections from the NAT Server) or some type of proxy server in the public subnet that would forward traffic to the database. This would become way too complex compared to the Software VPN option.

Comment: you got it almost right, I forgot to update this question after I had resolved it. You can see my comment above if you want to know why i need this. As for the solution, Yes we had a NAT gateway, I just didnt notice it (i wasnt the designer of this whole infrastructure). We assigned an elastic IP to our NAT gateway and we added security rules to the load balancer of data base to only allow access from IP address of NAT gateway. Kindly update your answer accordingly so people can find it easily. I am marking it as correct

Comment: You have a Load Balancer in front of your Database? That is a very unusual situation. (A reverse proxy I could understand, but why a Load Balancer?)

Comment: We are using an auto scaling group for most of our resources to ensure high availability and scalability. That is why we have to attach a load balancer with it to be able to access it. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Are you sure you have a Load Balancer in front of your database? Normally, a database only runs on one server, so there is no need to distribute traffic to multiple servers. A database certainly doesn't work with Auto Scaling.

Comment: Like i said, we are only using an autoscaling group so that if it shuts down because of any reason e.g load etc then a new instance starts automatically. Also the database is not on the same server as the web app.